# How to create a Heat Map in Python with Colorbar and hight resolution values in X, Y?

Tags: python, dictionary, heat

I have the next code in python to generate a 3D figure with MatPlotLib, but i need your help to change my code in order to be able to create a Heat Map instead the 3D figure.

My actual code:

Data Source-->
data.dat  contains:

*(1st column is 'x', 
2nd column is 'y' 
and third column is 'z')*

```
0.00    0.00    0.38
1.11    0.00    0.38
.
.
.
95.00    1.80    0.38
.
.
.
```

This file have 3231 similar rows...
Code:

```
**f_name='/home/data.dat'
data=np.loadtxt(f_name, delimiter='\t', unpack=True)
datos=np.array(data.tolist())
x = datos[0,:]
y = datos[1,:]
z = datos[2,:]
xi = np.linspace(min(x), max(x))
yi = np.linspace(min(y), max(y))
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
Z = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi)
Z[np.isnan(Z)] = 0
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
surf= ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet_r ,     linewidth=1, antialiased=True)
ax.set_zlim(-25, 25)
ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
ax.set_ylim(0, 102)
#more resolution:
start_x, end_x = ax.get_xlim()
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(start_x, end_x, 0.25))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%0.1f'))
start_y, end_y = ax.get_ylim()
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(start_y, end_y, 0.25))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%0.1f'))
#ColorBar:
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_title('3D Figure')
fig.savefig(pathfilename, dpi=300)**
```

so... i would like to generate a Heat Map using the same data source, when the 'z' column is the color depth, and also increase the X, Y resolution like in this 3D figure.

Can you help me?
Others Heat Map examples in this site are good reference but i do not understand exactly what changes i need to do in my actual code using my data source (data.dat).

Most of time, this code will execute offline.

I prefer a free library like MatPlotLib or another free solution that you know.

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You need to map the [-25, 25] z-axis values to RGB values.

Comment: Try [`seaborn`](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/).

Comment: [Visit the Gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html#), find something that has a feature you want, study the example code, try to adapt it to your problem, visit the [API docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar).